# Autograph on passport visa page. Can I travel to the US?

Tags: visas, passports, visa-refusals, passport-stamps, customs-and-immigration

I have a big work trip planned to the US in 3 weeks. I am worried about this autograph on one of the visa pages.

Has anyone ever had issues with this sort of thing, or any ways around it? I don't have enought time to get a new passport.

[image: autograph on passport]

Comment: I have scribbled all kinds of nonsense in some of my passport pages. Its never been brought up by immigration. So yes an officer can argue correctly that this is passport mutilation however I doubt it. Who says it wasn’t another immigration officer who did that *wink wink*?

Comment: @TheZealot I was kind of thinking the same thing.. like what are the rules about officials can they only do a stamp, or can they write on it too ? I see some stamps that have writing, anyway does all officials know every countries policy for doing a stamp. Im just worried as America is kind of different about some stuff and not as relaxed.

Comment: @CannonFodder not technically the same thing as that. this is a lot less intrusive as those doodles. not everyone has a massive doodle, but i can see a lot of people may have autographs

Comment: Next time you're collecting autographs, you might want to find something more suitable for them to sign.

Comment: is this your only blank page?

Comment: no, every other page is blank except for this one